# Finding out the fully qualified name of a type

Tags: typescript, express, visual-studio-code

I have a Node Express project in Typescript in Visual Studio Code.

The `express.Router` handler methods use the `Response` and `Request` parameters. Looking at the definition of the `Response` type, it is defined in node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts as:

```
export interface Response extends http.ServerResponse, Express.Response { ...
```

I now want to create a helper method that uses a parameter of this `Response` type. Unfortunately, the name `Response` on its own is ambiguous as there are more than one entities having that name.

How do I find out the fully qualified name of that `Response` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript doesn't really have 'qualified names', a module can only export one symbol with a specific name. Perhaps your IDE is showing it ambiguously, but assuming the module in question is called `[this-express-module]`, all you need to do is:

`import { Response } from "[this-express-module]";`

If this conflicts with a `Response` that is already imported in your module, you can do

`import { Response as MyResponse } from "[this-express-module]";`

Comment: Thanks. I have since found that Code Intellisense pops up a list of `Response` names, and I can move the cursor down each one to show where it is declared. After selecting one, Code will automatically create that import statement you have shown.